# Можно ли с кнопки на сайте запустить другой браузер?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, события

Господа, возник такой вопрос. Я у себя на сайте,  о поддержке IE вообще не думаю.  И честно говоря, данные статистики, что мол IE имеет львиную долю, на мой взгляд ошибочны, а потому, что просто установлены на всех компах (только OS Windows), но им ни кто не пользуется.. Да  суть не в этом... Но если вдруг на сайт зашел какой-нибудь незнайка, который не в курсе, что есть FF или Opera или Chrome и пользуется IE, понятно, что я могу ему ссылку на оф. сайты FF или Opera или Chrome. Но а вдруг посетитель на столько чайник, что у него установлены  FF или Opera или Chrome, а он им пользуется...  Вопрос, реально, чтобы при клике на кнопку на странице сайта, запустить один из выше перечисленных браузеров?

P.S. Господа, приводить какой нибудь пример как положено на сайте, я не могу, так как не имею малейшего представления вообще с чего начать...  Две просьбы. Или какой-нибудь конкретный пример или хотя бы подскажите куда копать...

Comment: Вроде бы нельзя. Потому что безопасность... Это же личный компьютер пользователя. Иначе хацкеры любили бы издеваться над пользователями запуская им все программы сразу по несколько раз с страниц в интернете

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, благодарю, процентов на 95 ))) был уверен, что нельзя... Но лучше спросить чем не знать точно)))

Comment: О, вернули 2007-й. IE11 и его преемник Edge превосходно работают, не надо их не поддерживать

Comment: @andreymal, против EDGE не имею ничего, доже не плох... скажу...  Но IE ...  даже выражаться не буду... Не мне тебя учить с твоим то опытом...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, привет, мне тут ответили,  недавно на этот вопрос, смотрел читал кое что и тут вспомнил такую штуку. Когда через  `IE или EDGE` что-то качаешь из сети, то  выдает окно запустить скаченный файл или просто скачать...  Если запустить, но файл скачается  и установится...  По сути получается, что браузер запускает .exe файл...  Я правильно думаю или чего то я не до понимаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Нет возможности запустить другой бразуер по нажатию кнопки,без вмешательства в security.

В нашем 2018, обычно данная уязвимость закрыта. В случае использования пользователем IE, если разрешен ActiveX(очень редкий случай) запустить свой сайт в другом браузере можно таким способом:

```
  var objShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.shell");
  objShell.run('start chrome stackoverflow.com');
  //start firefox stackoverflow.com
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Считывать заголовки запроса на предмет используемого клиентом браузера.
2. В случае если используется ИЕ выводить блок кнопок с изображениями браузеров со ссылками на их офф. сайты для скачивания и ***БОЛЬШУЮ ТАБЛИЧКУ***:

---

### Сайт не оптимизирован для работы в Интернет эксплорере.

### Пожалуйста, ипользуйте другой браузер.

---

Comment: Ну это я и так знаю))), и тем более это уже реализовано, надо было вопрос читать внимательнее)), но раз уж не поленился и написал ставлю плюс))))

Comment: Не совсем знаю... скорее догадываюсь, но лучше задать глупый вопрос, чем не знать точно)))